# use local dockerfile for building remote git repo

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use a repo which is build from RUST, but uses an old RUST version(1.36.0) which has build errors.
A newer version of RUST(1.51.0) does not have these build errors.

To partly automate it, I want to create a docker-compose file which pulls the git repo but use another Dockerfile for the build instead of the one present in the git repo.
Is that possible? or do I have to hack the RUST version fix another way.
(unfortunatly the repo owner does not commit the fix while it has been proposed)

my docker-compose file so far

```
%YAML 1.1
---
version: '3.8'
services:
  ping-exporter:
    build: https://github.com/knsd/ping-exporter.git
    image: ping-exporter
    container_name: ping_exporter
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9346:9346
    volumes:
      - "var/:/usr/local/scripts/:ro"
(...)
```